# Pi Zero W Wifi network connection issues

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-zero-w

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W project that needs a network connection for some of its functionality. The device normally does not have a keyboard and display attached, as it's operated by hardware switches and sensors. Most of the updating/debugging is done via an `ssh` connection. So it's a big pain if the WiFi connection goes bad.

What could be the possible explanation for the following WiFi connection problem:

The device boots up and the boot log kind of confirms that connecting to the network is successful:

```
[  OK  ] Started WPA supplicant
[  OK  ] Reached target Network
```

Running `$ ifconfig wlan0` shows that it has received its assigned IP address 192.168.x.x. But it can neither be pinged from another PC in the network nor the router address 192.168.1.1 can be pinged from the Pi. Actually, when trying to ping the Pi from another PC, instead of "Destination Host Unreachable" it just gets stuck, ping does not generate new retries.

Running `$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` gives a list of available networks, so apparently there is no problem with the antenna. Running `$ sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure` does not fix the situation.

And then, after a while, spontaneously, it can suddenly reconnect and everything is fine until it's not again.

**Update** with Info from comments:
I use just a plain raspbian default. When the device spontaneously reconnects, there are no connection problems, both from Pi and to Pi.

There are two wifi network configurations, one for the router, another for my mobile hotspot. But the hotspot is not active, and the IP address that I get with ifconfig wlan0 is the one that is properly assigned by the router's DHCP. Ok, I don't know, maybe it's not freshly received, maybe it's remembering the last address somehow.

Comment: Are you sure the AP Isolation of your router is disabled?

Comment: @M.Rostami that is definately not the issue. AP isolation is not enabled, and when the device has reconnected to the network, there is no issues whatsoever.

Comment: `Actually, when trying to ping the Pi from another PC, instead of "Destination Host Unreachable" it just gets stuck` have you a firewall on the pinged host ?

Comment: @Ephemeral no, just a plain raspbian default. When the device spontaneously reconnects, there are no connection problems, both from Pi and to Pi.

Comment: Is it configured for more than one wifi network, or has it only ever been connected to one?

Comment: @JohnS There are two wifi network configurations, one for router, other for my mobile hotspot. But the hotspot is not active, and the IP address that I get with `ifconfig wlan0` is the one that is properly assigned by the router's DHCP. Ok, I don't know, maybe it's not freshly received, maybe it's remembering the last address somehow.

Comment: Is the problem just on the router's hotspot? Or is it the same on the mobile's hotspot?

Comment: Check it out. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57278/44221

Comment: @M.Rostami Thanks, I'll see if some of those suggestions fix the situation convincingly. "Restart the router" is pretty crude fix, it does not provide explanation why other devices in the same network have no connectivity problems.

Comment: Alright, tell us the result. Thanks.

Comment: Please next time edit the question by yourself to add additional information. Comments are not a good place for that because not all users read them to understand the question. When you ping the RasPi and ping gets stuck, do you ping by ip address or by dns name?

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS DOES NOT use `wpa_cli` so this will do nothing. You have posted no diagnostics. Include `ip a && ip r` in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar issue. I solved by setting a static address via `dhcpcd.conf` for the Pi Zero since Raspian uses `dhcpcd` to manage network interfaces by default.

Pick and assign a static IP address for the Pi by editing the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file. It would look something like this:

```
interface wlan0
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
static ip_address=192.168.1.255/24 # Pi Zero selected address
static routers=192.168.1.1
```

I would also reserve the static address that you pick for the Pi from within the router (so it's not re-assigned to another device). Alternatively you can also set an IP range from the router to prevent it from ever assigning the address for the Pi.

More info about `dhcpd` static config [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd#Static_profile)

Comment: Why the problem solved by this procedure? Sound weird.